# License and our ezine

Tags: discussion, licensing, content-reuse

We have a GFDL ezine about the FOSS world. After consultation, we decided to add a section about an article that describes Q/A from unix.stackexchange or stackoverflow.com and so on for each number. What's the license of those sites' Q&A content?

Comment: Look at the bottom of any page... it's all there.

Comment: You mean each page is different?

Comment: No, I'm saying it's on the bottom of every page. ;) Whether it's different on any page I don't know but I doubt that would be the case. I'd expect it to be the same on any Stack Exchange site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All our content is licensed under [CC BY-SA](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) with [attribution required](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/):

> If you republish this content, we **require** that you:
>
> 1. **Visually indicate that the content is from Stack Overflow, Meta Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User** in some way. It doesn’t have to be obnoxious; a discreet text blurb is fine.
> 2. **Hyperlink directly to the original question** on the source site (e.g., `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345`)
> 3. **Show the author names** for every question and answer
> 4. **Hyperlink each author name** directly back to their user profile page on the source site (e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/users/12345/username)

This applies to every site in our network even though only four are mentioned in the blog post quoted above.

Comment: FOSS is very important for our ezine, So be sure we consider above considerations. thank you.